# InternalError: Failed copying input tensor when using CUDA GPU To Train Tensorflow Models in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, tensorflow

I started utilizing my GPU to train a CNN model for the Cats and Dogs dataset.
But when the run the model sometimes I get this error:
`InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized`

What should I do to prevent this?

Comment: Does your GPU have enough memory? :) If not, try to reduce the batch size / use a smaller model if appropriate.

Comment: Your GPU memory runing out of space for batches...reduce batch size

Comment: It's clearly votes are rigged...you posted similar question question yesterday same person answered with same votes

Answer (score 0):

The error message is generated when there is not enough memory in GPU when training usually caused by the batch size.

The simplest solution is to restart the kernel in your jupyter Lab and reduce the batch size to an optimal amount.

What you can do further is to monitor memory usage during runs and log run metadata, which then can be used to determine the optimal batch size. For this you can use [Tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard). Additionally, by default Tensorflow will try to allocate as much GPU memory as possible. You can change this using the GPUConfig options, so that Tensorflow will only allocate as much memory as needed. Check this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25138) out.

Note that repeatedly running your models can create overhead and it is best if you can restart your runtime from time to time to just clear everything out if you conducting very intensive experiments.